# t-sql "LIKE" and Pattern Matching

Tags: t-sql, pattern-matching, sql-like

I've found a small annoyance that I was wondering how to get around...

In a simplified example, say I need to return "TEST B-19" and "TEST B-20"

I have a where clause that looks like:

```
where [Name] LIKE 'TEST B-[12][90]'
```

and it works... unless there's a "TEST B-10" or "TEST-B29" value that I don't want.

I'd rather not resort to doing both cases, because in more complex situations that would become prohibitive.

I tried:

```
where [Name] LIKE 'TEST B-[19-20]'
```

but of course that doesn't work because it is looking for single characters...

Thoughts? Again, this is a very simple example, I'd be looking for ways to grab ranges from 16 to 32 or 234 to 459 without grabbing all the extra values that could be created.

EDITED to include test examples...

You might see "TEXAS 22" or "THX 99-20-110-B6" or "E-19" or "SOUTHERN B" or "122 FLOWERS" in that field. The presense of digits is common, but not a steadfast rule, and there are absolutely no general patterns for hypens, digits, characters, order, etc.

Comment: You can use CLR integration and Regular Expressions to avail yourself of the alternation operator `|` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would divide the `Name` column into the text parts and the number parts, and convert the number parts into an integer, and then check if that one was between the values. Something like:

```
where cast(substring([Name], 7, 2) as integer) between 19 and 20
```

And, of course, if the possible structure of [Name] is much more complex, you'd have to calculate the values for 7 and 2, not hardcode them....

EDIT: If you want to filter out the ones not conforming to the pattern first, do the following:

```
where [Name] LIKE '%TEST B-__%'
and cast(substring([Name], CHARINDEX('TEST B-', [Name]) + LEN('TEST B-'), 2) as integer) between 19 and 20
```

Maybe it's faster using `CHARINDEX` in place of the LIKE in the topmost line two, especially if you put an index on the computed value, but... That is only optimization... :)

EDIT: Tested the procedure. Given the following data:

```
jajajajajajajTEST B-100
jajajajajajajTEST B-85
jajajajjTEST B-100
jajjajajTEST B-100
jajajajajajajTEST B-00
jajajajaTEST B-100
jajajajajajajEST B-99
jajajajajajajTEST B-100
jajajajajajajTEST B-19
jajajajjTEST B-100
jajjajajTEST B-120
jajajajajajajTEST B-00
jajajajaTEST B-150
jajajajajajajEST B-20
TEST B-20asdfh asdfkh
```

The query returns the following rows:

```
jajajajajajajTEST B-19
TEST B-20asdfh asdfkh
```

Comment: Great solution, but you have predicted the issue. The values in [Name] have lots of variation, some of them may not even have numerals in them at all. I'd have to first filter the query down to only contain 'TEST B-##' results and then fire this, which is one more step than I was hoping for.

Comment: CHARINDEX() is returning 1, so it's trying to convert 'TE' to an integer. Seems like I'm missing something, and I see where you're going, but this query won't compile.

Comment: I'll try to compile it. I Have edited it, I forgot to add the length of the string to the index... Added a + LEN('TEST B-') to the second parameter of substring... I'll fire up SQL manager at get it to compile...

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of test data, I generated my own. I just removed the `Test B-` prefix, converted to int and did a `Between`

```
With Numerals As
(
    Select top 100 row_number() over (order by name)  TestNumeral
    from sys.columns
),
TestNumbers AS
(
    Select 'TEST B-' + Convert (VarChar, TestNumeral) TestNumber
    From Numerals
)
Select * 
From TestNumbers
Where Cast (Replace (TestNumber, 'TEST B-', '') as Integer) between 1 and 16
```

This gave me

```
TestNumber
-------------------------------------
TEST B-1
TEST B-2
TEST B-3
TEST B-4
TEST B-5
TEST B-6
TEST B-7
TEST B-8
TEST B-9
TEST B-10
TEST B-11
TEST B-12
TEST B-13
TEST B-14
TEST B-15
TEST B-16
```

This means, however, that if you have different strategies for naming tests, you would have to remove all different kinds of prefixes.

Now, on the other hand, if your Test numbers are in the `TEST-Space-TestType-Hyphen-TestNumber` format, you could use PatIndex and SubString

```
With Numerals As
(
    Select top 100 row_number() over (order by name)  TestNumeral
    from sys.columns
),
TestNumbers AS
(
    Select 'TEST B-' + Convert (VarChar, TestNumeral) TestNumber
    From Numerals
    Where TestNumeral Between 10 and 19
    UNION
    Select 'TEST A-' + Convert (VarChar, TestNumeral) TestNumber
    From Numerals
    Where TestNumeral Between 20 and 29
)
Select *
From TestNumbers
Where Cast (SubString (TestNumber, PATINDEX ('%-%', TestNumber)+1, Len (TestNumber) - PATINDEX ('%-%', TestNumber)) as Integer) between 16 and 26
```

That should yield the following

```
TestNumber
-------------------------------------
TEST A-20
TEST A-21
TEST A-22
TEST A-23
TEST A-24
TEST A-25
TEST A-26
TEST B-16
TEST B-17
TEST B-18
TEST B-19
```

All of your examples seem to have the test numbers at the end. So if you can create a table of patterns and then JOIN using a LIKE statement, you may be able make it work. Here is an example:

```
;
With TestNumbers As
(
      select 'E-1' TestNumber
union select 'E-2'
union select 'E-3'
union select 'E-4'
union select 'E-5'
union select 'E-6'
union select 'E-7'
union select 'SOUTHERN B1'
union select 'SOUTHERN B2'
union select 'SOUTHERN B3'
union select 'SOUTHERN B4'
union select 'SOUTHERN B5'
union select 'SOUTHERN B6'
union select 'SOUTHERN B7'
union select 'Southern CC'
union select 'Southern DD'
union select 'Southern EE'
union select 'TEST B-1'
union select 'TEST B-2'
union select 'TEST B-3'
union select 'TEST B-4'
union select 'TEST B-5'
union select 'TEST B-6'
union select 'TEST B-7'
union select 'TEXAS 1'
union select 'TEXAS 2'
union select 'TEXAS 3'
union select 'TEXAS 4'
union select 'TEXAS 5'
union select 'TEXAS 6'
union select 'TEXAS 7'
union select 'THX 99-20-110-B1'
union select 'THX 99-20-110-B2'
union select 'THX 99-20-110-B3'
union select 'THX 99-20-110-B4'
union select 'THX 99-20-110-B5'
union select 'THX 99-20-110-B6'
union select 'THX 99-20-110-B7'
union select 'Southern AA'
union select 'Southern CC'
union select 'Southern DD'
union select 'Southern EE'
),
Prefixes as
(
    Select 'TEXAS ' TestPrefix
    Union Select 'THX 99-20-110-B'
    Union Select 'E-'
    Union Select 'SOUTHERN B'
    Union Select 'TEST B-'
)
Select TN.TestNumber
From TestNumbers TN, Prefixes P
Where 1=1 
And TN.TestNumber Like '%' + P.TestPrefix + '%'
And Cast (REPLACE (Tn.TestNumber, p.TestPrefix, '') AS INTEGER) between 4 and 6
```

This will give you

```
TestNumber
----------------
E-4
E-5
E-6
SOUTHERN B4
SOUTHERN B5
SOUTHERN B6
TEST B-4
TEST B-5
TEST B-6
TEXAS 4
TEXAS 5
TEXAS 6
THX 99-20-110-B4
THX 99-20-110-B5
THX 99-20-110-B6

(15 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I like the cast(replace()) solution as well, I was just mostly hoping that there would be a way in the LIKE statement. The answer might be that it just can't be done there, in which case this would surely suffice.

Comment: Doesn't look like `LIKE` offers anything like this to me from the docs, no, sorry... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

Comment: Yeah, the test data should include all kinds of lengths, formats, etc. You might see "TEXAS 22" or "THX 99-20-110-B6" or "E-19" or "SOUTHERN B" in that field. That would be the beauty of being able to express a double digit numeric range in the LIKE statement between the brackets.

Comment: Thanks for all the input Raj. I went with Erik's solution since it solves the issue within the WHERE clause, since it's part of a bigger query. There are definitely some good techniques in your soultion(s) that I'll refer to in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Wildcards or no, you still have to edit the query every time you want to change the range definition.  If you're always dealing with a range (and it's not always the same range), you might use parameters.  For example:

*note: for some reason (this has happened in many other posts as well), when I try to post code beginning with 'declare', SO hangs and times-out.  I reported it on meta already, but nobody could reproduce it (including me).  Here it's happening again, so I took the 'D' off, and now it works.*  I'll come back tomorrow, and it will let me put the 'D' back on.

```
DECLARE @min varchar(5)
DECLARE @max varchar(5)

SET @min = 'B-19'
SET @max = 'B-20'

SELECT
   ...
WHERE NAME BETWEEN @min AND @max
```

You should avoid formatting [NAME] as others have suggested (using function on it) -- this way, your search can benefit from an index on it.

In any case -- you might re-consider your table structure.  It sounds like 'TEST B-19' is a composite (non-normalized) value of category ('TEST') + sub-category ('B') + instance ('19').  Put it in a lookup table with 4 columns (id being the first), and then join it by id in whatever query needs to output the composite value.  This will make searching and indexing much easier and faster.

Comment: The names in the field are entities, and do follow a localized convention (general rule - does not apply in every case), but my data is the global dataset, and unless I wrote a normalization script for each region, there really is no rule I can go by across the board.

Answer (score 0):

Is this acceptable:

```
WHERE [Name] IN ( 'TEST B-19', 'TEST B-20' )
```

The list of values can come from a subquery, e.g.:

```
WHERE [Name] IN ( SELECT [Name] FROM Elsewhere WHERE ... )
```

Comment: That would work in the simple cases, but the more complex ones would get a little drawn out. The subquery solution could work as well, but mostly it just pushes the issue down to the subquery level. It's that where clause where I'd want to incorporate the pattern matching. Thanks for the suggestion!